# Blue Ocean "Repository URL - Please enter a valid URL."

Tags: git, jenkins-blueocean

I'm trying to create a Pipeline with my git repo in Blue Ocean, but whatever I enter in the text field I get the error 'Repository URL - Please enter a valid URL'. The Jenkins run through a Docker container.

I tried:

```
ssh://git@<my-host>:/home/git/repos/Genpcap.git
ssh://git@<my-host>:/home/git/repos/Genpcap
git@<my-host>:/home/git/repos/Genpcap.git
git@<my-host>:/home/git/repos/Genpcap
```

I have confirmed that the network is connected and the git service is available, any ideas?

Comment: None of those look like a URL. A colon precedes a port, not a path.

Comment: This is the docs for Git URL syntax: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls . That is, an URL should be either `ssh://git@<my-host>/home/git/repos/Genpcap.git` or `git@<my-host>:/home/git/repos/Genpcap.git`. Perhaps could be shortened to `git@<my-host>:repos/Genpcap.git`. Before putting your URL in Jenkins try it from the command line: `git ls-remote git@<my-host>:repos/Genpcap.git`

Answer (score 0):

- Open Github/Gitlab/BitBucket project home and click on the **clone** button to copy the url.
- Go to Jenkins, add a new pipeline selecting the **git** the right git flavour.

Comment: I did not use Github/Gitlab, only a standalone Git service on my server. I used the following command to clone the project and it worked:

`git clone git@<my-host>:/home/git/repos/Genpcap.git`

Comment: In Jenkins did you select the generic git button during the pipeline creation? Can Jenkins reach your git server?

Comment: Yes, I selected the generic git button, and Jenkins can access my git server.

Comment: Please, inspect the Jenkins logs. Unfortunately I have no more information to better help you.